# Is posting topic related material (not solution) wrong in any way?

Tags: discussion

There was an active post about an Harry Potter kind off animated series running on Indian television. The 1st answer itself was answer. But I posted related material, which was about, one Indian movie which was cheap version of Harry Potter and another superhero based series which borrowed (copied) basic concepts from Harry Potter.

Since, secondary topic of concern was "Harry Potter being copied on Indian television", I just shared 2 other such occurrence, did I break any rule?

(If I have broken any rule, please deduct points from Gryffindor, I belong there)

Comment: If you have *relevant* material (eg that might help someone else answer the question) then you can write or link to it in a brief comment.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes, it's wrong. It's naughty. It's....[taboo](http://friends.wikia.com/wiki/The_One_Where_Ross_Dates_A_Student/Transcript) (pause for shivers).**

Your answers should be **answers to the question asked**, not an attempt to pass on additional (non-relevant) information that you've uncovered.

We've all been there. While we've been researching a topic, we've come across something interesting that practically *cries out* to be shared far and wide despite not ultimately answering the question that the OP posted. **Resist that urge.** Save it for comments or, if you simply gotta tell someone, pose your own question and frame your interesting info as a new answer.

From the FAQ under "[How do I write a good answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)"

> **Answer the question :** *Read the question carefully. **What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer
>   provides that***

Comment: On other sites, good answers often do both: they answer the question *and* they provide additional material that is not strictly part of the answer. Is that acceptable here?

Comment: @BrianDrake - That's a tough question to answer without seeing what you've written, but in the main I would suggest keeping the answer and throwing the irrelevant crap into the bin or at least putting it right at the bottom with an ["*It might also interest you to know"*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A20774+%22interest+you%22). It might interest you to know that I'm the guiltiest person on the site of doing this.